# Pseudo transparency with PyQT

Tags: python, pyqt, transparency, screenshot

I want to create a pseudo-transparent window by taking a screenshot of what would be behind the window if it wasn't there using PyQt. The following code takes a screenshot:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from PyQt4.QtGui import *

app = QApplication([])
widget = QWidget()
widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
label = QLabel()
widget.layout().addWidget(label)

def shoot():
    geometry = widget.geometry()
    widget.hide()
    label.setPixmap(QPixmap.grabWindow(QApplication.desktop().winId(), x = geometry.x(), y = geometry.y(), height = geometry.height(), width = geometry.width())
    widget.show()

widget.layout().addWidget(QPushButton('Screenshot', clicked = shoot))
widget.show()
app.exec_()
```

But although there's the widget.hide(), the window itself appears on the screenshot. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Have you tried waiting (`time.sleep()`) for a while between `widget.hide()` and setting the label's Pixmap? Maybe the widget isn't hidden yet when you take the screenshot. Alternatively, have you tried actual transparency, using `widget.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)`?

Comment: Thanks, it actually works if I add a 0.3 second sleep after widget.hide(). But how can I know how long to wait? Is there a way to simply wait until the hide event is finished?

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I wrote that essentially does what you are looking for. It uses the resizable Qt Window to take a screenshot of whatever is behind it. So far this script only works for 1 screen. Diving into `QScreen` and `QApplication` will probably give you the answer to make this extendable.

```py
import sys
import io
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt, QBuffer
from PIL import Image


class Screenshooter(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.snapBtn = QPushButton("Capture", self)
        self.snapBtn.clicked.connect(self.take_screenshot)
        self.show()

    def take_screenshot(self):
        geometry = self.geometry()
        screen = self.parent.screenAt(self.pos())
        full_screenshot = screen.grabWindow(
            0,
            geometry.x(),
            geometry.y(),
            geometry.width(),
            geometry.height()
        )
        full_image = full_screenshot.toImage()
        buffer = QBuffer()
        buffer.open(QBuffer.ReadWrite)
        full_image.save(buffer, 'PNG')
        im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(buffer.data()))
        im.show()
        buffer.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = Screenshooter(app)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that instead of sleeping for an unknown amount of time, `app.processEvents()` should also work. This forces the Qt app to complete ongoing stuff -such as hiding widgets- before continuing. [**This**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608557/resizing-a-dialog-with-pyqt4) is a related question where this is discussed in one of the answers.

Comment: Seems like processEvents() does not last long enough. I also tried while self.isHidden() == False: sleep(0.1), but this also does not wait long enough. The window flickers a bit, but the screenshot does not show the desktop behind it.